# How to blend transition between web pages to give the illusion that the visitor has never left the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I was just thinking, and thought it would be cool if there was some trick to make it seem like when the user clicks on a new page, like on the main menubar that is identical across the site, if there could be a seamless transition that gives the illusion that the data changes but they haven't gone anywhere, even though they are really now on an entirely new web page.

Comment: Hmmm... isn't that why ajax is there?

Comment: Also, to add to the experience, you might want to download (but not show) data of possible next pages so that when the user does make the request for those resources, it is fetched from the browser cache instead of from the server. The user won't have to wait as long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do that these days is *to not load* an entirely new web page (if that kind of experience is your goal).

The easiest way to do so is jquery.load:
http://api.jquery.com/load/